# When I want to see what I am writing in Texmaker, I get this message

Tags: texmaker

I would like to see what I write in TexMaker and I follow the instructions in [this youtube site](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoDv0qhyysQ&t=400s), but I get continuously the Alert message in the following picture. What I do wrong, please?

[image]

Comment: Te maker cannot load your tex installation. What do you use? Miktex? Texlive ? You probably want to check "options"  and "configure texmaker". A screenshot of those could help.

Comment: You are aware that TeXMaker is just an editor? You still need to install a latex installation like MikTeX or TeXLive. Or you can use overleaf.com where everything runs in the browser, no installation required.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It is always better to copy & paste the relevant code and the error message instead of making a screenshot of it and choose a more descriptive title. If you want to set the text size to 12pt the option of article should be `12pt`. However, the cause of the error here is probably, as suggested in the other comments, a missing installation of LaTeX.

Comment: @daleif, I have installed MikTeX, but it does not work either, any other suggestions please?

Comment: can you compile on the command line?

Comment: Usually the TeX/LaTeX-File starts with \documentclass... What lines are in front of this?

Comment: @daleif, yes I can.

Comment: @daleif, when I save  a file, I have to save it in a specific folder?

Comment: Not really. Have you restarted your editor or Windows after you installed LaTeX? And as Harald mentions are are a bit worried about the code in the image, you haven't got that bibtex just sitting at the top any more right?

Comment: @daleif, sorry to ask but what is bibtex?

Comment: A bibliography compiler.

Comment: You should probably have a look at some introductional material about latex and friends. See fx https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/